# Ubuntu 11.04 не грузится с Live CD

Tags: ubuntu

Есть релиз убунты 11.04 скачанный с сайта (сд + двд образы), проверил по мд5 - все оке. Записал на болванки, хотел загрузить без установки, дабы разбить жесткий диск на разделы, подготовив ноутбук (HP g62 b26-er) к установке... Но грузиться лайв сиди не захотел. После выбора варианта запуска без установки появлялся черный экран.Погуглив, нашел для данной версии подобные вопросы, освещавшиеся тут: - [11.04 Live CD Doesn't Work (Black Screen)][1] - [Ubuntu 11.04 blank screen on boot.][2] - [Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2 Live CD - Blank Screen][3]Третий вариант сразу отпадает, ибо там человеку сказали что раз у вас бета, то может быть. У меня не бета. В первом варианте ничего толкового я не нашел, там речь идет об апдейтах и о том что надо чуваку погуглить... Во втором варианте нашел умный совет - выбрать опцию “nomodeset”. Выбрал, после этого нет черного экрана! Пошел экран загрузки убунты.. Точки весело меняются, жизнь идет, а потом замирает. За 10 минут ни одна точка не изменилась в цвете, откуда я пришел к выводу, что процесс запуска завис. (конечно же, процесс повторялся неоднократно).Вот такой фейл. Буду рад выслушать ваши идеи. Просьба не пестрить умностями типа "погугли", ибо оттуда я и пришел на данный сайт в надежде получить ответ от добрых людей. Заранее спасибо.  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41549/11-04-live-cd-doesnt-work-black-screen  [2]: http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/ubuntu-11-04-blank-screen-on-boot-solved/  [3]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если цель разбить диск, скачайте gparted, всё равно в убунте - он же.) Вот ссылка: [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) - скачайте лайв-сиди, попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Предложения следующие:

1. Загружаться не с CD/DVD, а воспользоваться флэш-носителем.
2. Вместо обычного образа, опробовать дополнительный (alternative).

Comment: с флеш та же песняпробовал дополнительный - там вообще нет возможности запуска без установки

Comment: Ок. Тогда попробуйте предыдущие версии Ubuntu. Если вам нужно только разбить диск без установки, то для вас не должна быть критична версия поставки. И если не ошибаюсь, дополнительный режим позволяет разбить диск вручную в процессе установки, а затем установку прервать.

Answer (score 0):

Asus-k42, сейчас установил, удалил винду совсем, но хочу сказать, что стоял виндовский блокировщик, проверьте.